# Java: MigLayout Center Center not working | alternative for absolute positioning

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, miglayout

The element won't center vertically, and I don't know why. I've tried "center center", but it's not working.
[image: vertical problem with components]

MigLayout

```
private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("center center, filly"));
```

Components

```
panel.add(header, "span");
panel.add(input, "split 4");
panel.add(unit1);
panel.add(to);
panel.add(unit2, "wrap");
panel.add(convert, "span");
panel.add(output, "span");
```

I want to center the components, but **not** using absolute positioning (because I know how to center using this method)

Comment: `GridBagLayout`

Comment: Absolute positioning is not a good alternative. Other layout manager (or better still managers) is. I am not sure what we are suppose to understand from "The element won't center vertically". What does "the element mean"  ? Post [mcve] and add to it the desired layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Shame on you but

- `center center` is not `center, center`
- `center, center, filly` - `filly` mitigates the vertical center
- To align individual components, you need `align center` - For example, `panel.add(new JLabel("Header"), "span, align center");`

---

Assuming you are asking how to horizontally align the components, you need to specify that per component. However, first it is best to look at what the following line of code actually does.

```
private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("center center, filly"));
```

Or more specifically, what the following extract means.

```
new MigLayout("center center, filly")
```

`center center` - This horizontally aligns the packed components on the `JPanel`.

[image]

Assuming you were trying to get the components centered vertically as well as horizontally, you would actually need `center, center`. Notice the `,` between the two `center` keywords.

[image]

`filly` - Well to quote the white paper, *"Claims all available space in the container for the columns and/or rows"*.

This pretty much mitigates the effect of "center, center" and all you really need is `center, filly`.

---

Now to horizontally align components across multiple columns, you need to add the keywords `align center` to each component you want to do this on. For example

```
panel.add(new JLabel("Header"), "span, align center");
```

An example of this with your components would be

```
String[] dummyList  = new String[] {
    "Val 1",
    "Val 2"
};
JPanel migPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("center, filly")); //Maybe you wanted center, center. I'm not sure
migPanel.add(new JLabel("Header"), "span, align center");
migPanel.add(new JTextField("Input"), "split 4");
migPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList));
migPanel.add(new JLabel("To"), "span");
migPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList), "wrap");
migPanel.add(new JButton("Convert"), "span, align center");
migPanel.add(new JTextField("Output"), "span, align center");
```

---

As [MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) mentioned there are other layouts that can be used to achieve a very similar look to what you had; [`GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) being the easiest.

Using a mixture of `GridBagConstraints` you can achieve a very similar layout.

For example,

```
String[] dummyList  = new String[] {
    "Val 1",
    "Val 2"
};
JPanel gridBagPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

gc.weighty = 1; //Delete this line if you are after an equivalent of `center, center` from the MigLayout
gc.gridwidth = 4;
gridBagPanel.add(new JLabel("Header"), gc);

gc.gridy = 1;
gc.gridwidth = 1;
gridBagPanel.add(new JTextField("Input"), gc);

gc.gridx = 1;
gridBagPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList), gc);

gc.gridx = 2;
gridBagPanel.add(new JLabel("To"), gc);

gc.gridx = 3;
gridBagPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList), gc);

gc.gridy = 2;
gc.gridx = 0;
gc.gridwidth = 4;
gridBagPanel.add(new JButton("Convert"), gc);

gc.gridy = 3;
gridBagPanel.add(new JTextField("Output"), gc);
```

---

Runnable Example - **LayoutExample.java**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LayoutExample extends JFrame {
    private JTabbedPane tabs;
    private JPanel migPanel;
    private JPanel gridBagPanel;
    private JPanel migPanelCC;
    private JPanel gridBagPanelCC;
    private String[] dummyList  = new String[] {
        "Val 1",
        "Val 2"
    };

    private LayoutExample() {
        super("Layout Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setUpTabs();
        add(tabs);

        setSize(800, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setUpTabs() {
        tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        setUpMig();
        tabs.add(migPanel, "Mig Panel");

        setUpMigCC();
        tabs.add(migPanelCC, "Mig Panel Center Center");

        setUpGridBag();
        tabs.add(gridBagPanel, "Grid Bag Panel");

        setUpGridBagCC();
        tabs.add(gridBagPanelCC, "Grid Bag Panel Center Center");
    }

    private void setUpMig() {
        migPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("center, filly"));
        addToMigPanel(migPanel);
    }

    private void setUpMigCC() {
        migPanelCC = new JPanel(new MigLayout("center, center"));
        addToMigPanel(migPanelCC);
    }

    private void addToMigPanel(JPanel mPanel) {
        mPanel.add(new JLabel("Header"), "span, align center");
        mPanel.add(new JTextField("Input"), "split 4");
        mPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList));
        mPanel.add(new JLabel("To"), "span");
        mPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList), "wrap");
        mPanel.add(new JButton("Convert"), "span, align center");
        mPanel.add(new JTextField("Output"), "span, align center");
    }

    private void setUpGridBag() {
        gridBagPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gc.weighty = 1;
        addToGridBagPanel(gridBagPanel, gc);
    }

    private void setUpGridBagCC() {
        gridBagPanelCC = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();

        addToGridBagPanel(gridBagPanelCC, gc);
    }

    private void addToGridBagPanel(JPanel gblPanel, GridBagConstraints gc) {
        gc.gridwidth = 4;
        gblPanel.add(new JLabel("Header"), gc);

        gc.gridy = 1;
        gc.gridwidth = 1;
        gblPanel.add(new JTextField("Input"), gc);

        gc.gridx = 1;
        gblPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList), gc);

        gc.gridx = 2;
        gblPanel.add(new JLabel("To"), gc);

        gc.gridx = 3;
        gblPanel.add(new JComboBox<String>(dummyList), gc);

        gc.gridy = 2;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridwidth = 4;
        gblPanel.add(new JButton("Convert"), gc);

        gc.gridy = 3;
        gblPanel.add(new JTextField("Output"), gc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new LayoutExample());
    }
}
```

---

Finally, it is a bad idea to use absolute positioning. This is because when the container changes size, the components within the container will not automatically adjust. This will not work well for most things as you could lose important UI components pretty fast or you could have loads of extra white space.